# How to use two "using" statement in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

my data file is in the following format

```
bcntgsytlz 161
icakwnsmi  1004
hwrpqninc  1686
fmjlrytx   638
ovhwmevij  3267
cdwgimlus  11071
```

Now for printing labels i need to use xticlabels command

```
set xtics rotate by 90 right
plot 'c.txt' using 2:xticlabels(1)
```

for plotting historgram i need to use

```
set style histogram
set style fill solid
set boxwidth 0.5
plot 'c.txt' using 2:xtic(1) with boxes
```

How to use both xticlabels and xtic in a single statement

Comment: I don't understand your problem: `xtic` is only a shortcut for `xticlabels`. BTW: Your second plot is not a histogram, but plotted `with boxes`. `set style histogram` is a global replacement for `plot ... with histogram`, see https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/gnuplot/4302/2d-plotting-styles/15032/selecting-a-plotting-style#t=201707041331309519603

Comment: problem solved thanks i didn't know xtic was shortcut to xticlabels